# What is "input endpoint" and "internal endpoint" in azure cloud platform?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cloud-services

What is "input endpoint" and "Internal endpoint" in azure? How do i create new "input endpoint"? & How can i send data to "input endpoint"?

What is input endpoint port 65400 port?

Comment: Can you give more details? Which service in Azure are you referring to?

Answer (score 6):

An Input Endpoint is a port / route between your Cloud Service and Internet.

An Internal EndPoint is a port / route only accessible to apps in your Cloud Service Package, without external access. This can help you to make secure direct connection between two apps in your package.

You can configure EndPoints in your Cloud Service Configuration files. I think this [blog post](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/configuring-internal-endpoints-on-azure-cloud-services/) will help you.

Regards,